# Conditional division of values within a data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, division

First let me exclaim that I am fairly new with R, and this may be easy for an experienced user.
I have been trying to figure out how I can perform a conditional division of values within a data frame. Specifically, I have a data frame (as the one below `df1`) with several identifiers. I want to divide the values with values in a vector or df (`df2`) with matching unique identifiers (like the one below), while keeping the identifiers intact.

```
ID = c("nr6536","nr8798","nr8723","nr8276","nr7774","nr0093")
Conc = c("1:2","1:4","1:2","1:8","1:4","1:4")
ID1 = c("ID","Conc","Eb","Eb","Sd","Sd","Re","Sd")
ID2 = c("Re","Sd","Eb")
dat1 = c(2,3,4,5,6,7)
dat2 = c(8,9,10,11,12,13)
dat3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
dat4 = c(4,3,2,7,6,5)
dat5 = c(8,7,6,3,4,8)
dat6 = c(6,4,2,5,3,8)
dat7 = c(9,2,7)

df1 = data.frame(ID,Conc,dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5,dat6)
colnames(df1)=ID1
df2 = data.frame(t(dat7)); colnames(df2)=ID2
rm(ID,Conc,ID1,ID2,dat1, dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5,dat6,dat7)
```

Wanted output:

```
    ID      Conc  Eb      Eb      Sd   Sd   Re     Sd
    nr6536  1:2   0.2857  1.1429  0.5  2    0.8889 3
    nr8798  1:4   0.4286  1.2857  1    1.5  0.7778 2
    nr8723  1:2   0.5714  1.4286  1.5  1    0.6667 1
    nr8276  1:8   0.7143  1.5714  2    3.5  0.3333 2.5
    nr7774  1:4   0.8571  1.7143  2.5  3    0.4444 1.5
    nr0093  1:4   1       1.8571  3    2.5  0.8889 4
```

I have tried with `ave`,`tabulate` and with `ifelse` but fail to get the desired output. A non-functional example of this is given below:

```
library(reshape2)
df1.2 = melt(df1)
df2names = colnames(df2)
df2.2 = as.data.frame(t(df2)); df2.2$variable=df2names

df3 = as.data.frame(apply(df1.2,1,function(x){
                    ScaVal = ifelse(x$variable %in% df2.2$variable, value/df2.2$V1)
                    return(ScaVal)
}))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how this can be done? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you want to do.  What does `I want to divide the values with values in a vector or df with matching unique identifiers` mean?  What is the role of `df2` here?  Can you please provide a specific example, within the data you've provided, of a calculation that should be executed to get your desired output?

Comment: My apologies for not providing a clearer description of my intensions.
If the column name of `df1` matches the column name of `df2` then divide the values in that df1 column by the matching value in `df2`. This should be applied to the whole set of values in `df1`. Does that make it clear what I’m trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally prefer a `tidyverse` solution, but since you don't have unique variable names in `df1` you're going to run into problems with that. Instead, have a base R solution using a `for loop` (shocking, I know!). Unless you have millions of columns in your data frame, though, I don't think you'll have any problems with performance.

```
conditional_divide <- function(df1, df2) {
    for (i in seq_len(ncol(df1))) {
        if (colnames(df1)[i] %in% colnames(df2)) {
            df1[,i] <- df1[,i] / df2[[colnames(df1)[i]]]
        }
    }
    return(df1)
}

conditional_divide (df1, df2)

      ID Conc        Eb       Eb  Sd  Sd        Re  Sd
1 nr6536  1:2 0.2857143 1.142857 0.5 2.0 0.8888889 3.0
2 nr8798  1:4 0.4285714 1.285714 1.0 1.5 0.7777778 2.0
3 nr8723  1:2 0.5714286 1.428571 1.5 1.0 0.6666667 1.0
4 nr8276  1:8 0.7142857 1.571429 2.0 3.5 0.3333333 2.5
5 nr7774  1:4 0.8571429 1.714286 2.5 3.0 0.4444444 1.5
6 nr0093  1:4 1.0000000 1.857143 3.0 2.5 0.8888889 4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using [`purrr::reduce()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html) (part of `tidyverse`).
Note: It does involve allowing `df1` to take on unique column names.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 %>% setNames(make.names(names(.), unique = TRUE))
values <- df2 %>% unlist(.)

update <- function(df, val, name) mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with(name)), funs(./val))

reduce2(values, names(values), update, .init=df1)
```

Output:

```
      ID Conc       Eb    Eb.1  Sd Sd.1       Re Sd.2
1 nr6536  1:2 0.285714 1.14286 0.5  2.0 0.888889  3.0
2 nr8798  1:4 0.428571 1.28571 1.0  1.5 0.777778  2.0
3 nr8723  1:2 0.571429 1.42857 1.5  1.0 0.666667  1.0
4 nr8276  1:8 0.714286 1.57143 2.0  3.5 0.333333  2.5
5 nr7774  1:4 0.857143 1.71429 2.5  3.0 0.444444  1.5
6 nr0093  1:4 1.000000 1.85714 3.0  2.5 0.888889  4.0
```

If you want to get the column names back to the way they were (although non-unique column names are not recommended), use `rename()`:

```
purrr::reduce2(values, names(values), update, .init=df1) %>%
  rename_at(vars(matches("\\.\\d")), funs(str_replace(., "\\.\\d", "")))
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see from your output that your script produces the desired output, and the `.1` `.2` added to the column names wouldn't be a problem. However, when I run it, my R throws an error `Error in reduce_init(.x, .init, left = .left) : object 'foo' not found`. I updated the purrr package, but the error remains... My R must have an issue. I appreciate your assistance nonetheless.

Comment: sorry, old code there.  fixed now. the bottom line (with rename_at) has the right values.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't... R throws this error: `Error in mutate_at(df, vars(starts_with(name)), funs(./val)) : 
  could not find function "mutate_at"` Which I take it to mean that I lack a package that calls that function... But I have not pursued it further, as the `for` loop suggested by divibisan works. I do appreciate your assistance though. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see.  You need `library(tidyverse)`.  Sorry, two sloppy errors in a row!

Comment: Okay, thanks!  The script works perfectly after I installed `tidyverse`. I will keep this script, as I think I have a use for it for another data set.